# Fatal error: unknown C primitive `Base_am_testing'

Tags: ocaml, flowtype, ocamlbuild

After building [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) with [make](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/Makefile#L247) like `make build-flow-debug` and running it with [ocamlrun](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/runtime.html) like `ocamlrun bin/flow check local-test/test.js` I'm getting following error

```
Fatal error: unknown C primitive `Base_am_testing'
```

I think the error has something to do with [ocaml base](https://docs.mirage.io/base/Base__Import/index.html), but I'm not sure. I'm thinking of some kind of linking issue but i'm not familiar enough with OCaml to fix this on my own. I'm using OCaml and ocamlrun version 4.05.0.

Any advice on how can I fix this?